# Plotting two vectors of different sizes, only want to plot matching column names

Tags: r, plot

I'm in grad school and am on the steep R learning curve at the moment.

I'm trying to plot data from a clinical study that uses randomized patient IDs which I have set up as the column names.  The study had two parts and some patients participated in only one part, X, and then dropped out so X has more values than Y.  Thus, I want to make a scatterplot of X vs Y using only the patients that participated in both studies.  The patient numbers are quite large so I cant just manually remove patients that only did part X.

Any help?

Basically my two sets of data look like this:

X
:

```
ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4
1    2    3    4
```

Y:

```
ID2  ID4
6    7
```

I've tried to do something like:
plot(x[,colnames(y)],y)

To try and only plot the values from X that have the column names in Y but this obviously didn't work.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try doing `df1[, names(df2)]` instead.

Comment: Hmm trying this I am getting the error "undefined columns selected"

Comment: Do you also have new ID's that only appear in Y, but not X?

Comment: If so, X[,intersect(names(Y), names(X))] and Y[,intersect(names(Y), names(X))] will provide you with the columns of each that are shared.

Comment: Ah, yes that was it!  There are new IDs in Y as well.  Thank you so much!